# why is there a difference when assigning value to a dict initialised with dict.fromkeys() and with curly braces?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

This is an example,

```
my_keys=['hi','hello']
d=dict.fromkeys(my_keys,[])
print d
d['hello'].append([1,])
print d['hello']
print d['hi']

d={'hi': [], 'hello': []}
print d
d['hello'].append([1,])
print d['hello']
print d['hi']
```

Output:

```
{'hi': [], 'hello': []}
[[1]]
[[1]]
{'hi': [], 'hello': []}
[[1]]
[]
```

With the output, it can seen that when the value of one key is modified, that is `d['hello'].append([1,])` changes the value of key 'hi' if the dict is initialised with `dict.fromkeys()`

> *classmethod* `fromkeys(seq[, value])`
>   create a new dictionary with keys from *seq* and values set to *value*.

why is there a difference when assigning value to a dict initialised with `dict.fromkeys()`  and with curly braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys()` does not make a copy of the value you pass in, so you have just **one** list object. Your `{...}` dict literal creates **two separate lists**.

Remember that in Python names, attributes and objects contained in a container like a list or dictionary are just *references* to objects on the heap. You can easily create multiple references to the same object. `dict.fromkeys()` just takes the reference you pass in and re-use that for all values. So all values in `d` just point to the same list object:

```
>>> my_keys = ['hi', 'hello']
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(my_keys)
>>> d['hi'] is d['hello']
True
>>> id(d['hi']), id(d['hello'])
(4508307448, 4508307448)
```

Use a dict comprehension to create a dictionary from a list of keys where you need to produce separate objects for the values:

```
{k: [] for k in my_keys}
```

In a dict comprehension the value expression is evaluated for each iteration of the `for` loop, so the `[]` expression is executed again and again to produce individual separate list objects:

```
>>> d = {k: [] for k in my_keys}
>>> d['hi'] is d['hello']
False
>>> id(d['hi']), id(d['hello'])
(4514233544, 4514233672)
```